# appengine - ftp alternatives

Tags: google-app-engine, ftp

I have an appengine app and I need to receive files from Third Parties.

The best option to me is to receive the files via ftp, but I have read that it is not possible, at least a year ago.

It is still not possible? Which way could I receive the files?

This is very important to my project, in fact it is indispensable.

Thx a lot!!!!

Comment: It is not possible using FTP.  Write your own handler and/or use the BlobStore if the files are large.  Your users can use a form, or you can write a program to upload to your app via HTTP POSTs.  Hard to suggest more without more details.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean with the second option? (I´m a newbie). It is essential that the solution be automatic. There are some files in other server and I need a way to send them automatically, something like every minute check new files and sent them to my appengine folder or blobstore or anywhere in my app. Could I have an app in a normal server that insert directly into my blobstore? Is there a way that appengine can check folders in other servers? Any other ideas? Thx a lot!!

Comment: I meant the first option, the one about the handler...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [Blobstore](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html).

**Edit**: To post to the blobstore in Java, the code fragment in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177252/using-http-post-on-an-android-device-to-put-data-on-google-app-engines-blob-stor) should work (this was for Android; elsewhere, use e.g. [Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html)). The URL to post to must have been created with [createUploadUrl](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Uploading_a_Blob). The simplest way to communicate it to the source server might be a GET URL, e.g. "/makeupload" which is text/plain and contains only the URL to POST to. To prevent unauthorized uploads, you can require a password either in the POST, or already in the GET (e.g. as a query parameter)

Comment: Like I wrote in the other comment. How could it be automatic from other server?

Comment: The other server needs to make a HTTP POST request to upload the file. You will need to write some code for that - what programming language do you want to use?

Comment: Hi Martin, thx for the quick responses. It looks great!. I´m going to make some tests and coordinate with the third party. I´ll tell you the results next week. Thx in advance!

Comment: Hi Martin, I think I don't understand you at all. I have some problems:

Comment: Did you read the description of the blobstore API? If yes: do you agree that it would solve your problem? If yes: please post any question that you have on using it as a separate SO question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depend a lot of the size range of your imports. For small files the Urlfetch API will be sufficient.

I myself tend to import large CSV files ranging from 70–800 MB, in which case the legacy Blobstore and HTTP-POST doesn't cut it. GAE cannot handle HTTP requests >32 MB directly, nor can you upload static files >32 MB for manual import.

Traditionally, I've used a *nix relay for downloading the data files, splitting them into well-formed JSON segments and then submitting maybe 10-30 K HTTP-POST requests back to GAE. all inputs into well-formed. This used to be the only viable work-around, and for >1 GB files it might still come across as the preferred method due to scaling performance (complex import procedures is easily distributed across hundreds of F1 instances).

Luckily, as of [April 9 this year (SDK 1.7.7)](http://googleappengine.blogspot.se/2013/04/app-engine-177-released.html) importing large files directly to GAE isn't much of a problem any longer. Outbound sockets are generally available to all billing-enabled apps, and consequently you'd easily solve the "large files" issue by opening up an FTP connection and downloading.

Sockets API Overview (Python): https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/